# How do I monitor network usage on a Windows server?

Tags: windows, networking, bandwidth

I would like to monitor server bandwidth usage.

The server OS is Windows Server 2012

This should give me as result the amount of data over a certain period of time and separate it by protocol and by remote IP.

Protocol to discriminate would be HTTP, FTP and RDP at least.

How can I do this?

Comment: What version of Windows server?

Comment: 2012, I edited the question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend Nagios. It has a very intuitive interface and still meets any Enterprise needs. You can run it on upto 7 nodes for free.

https://www.nagios.com/downloads/nagios-xi/

Personally i haven't used it before but Microsoft has a network monitor too. I do not know if the reporting functionality meets your needs:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that is actually a bit easier than PTRG so I give you the solution mark.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this on Spiceworks when I've had a similar need: http://www.paessler.com/prtg

It's free up to 100 sensors which is more than sufficient for monitoring a single server. It takes a bit of reading but works well.

You can mess around with the Resource Monitor as well but it has a bigger performance impact.

If you're on a corporate network your network guys can probably just give you that data though.

Comment: thanks for that, I had a look at it and seems to be overkill for my needs. I am actually not on a corporate network and I am the one (with my limited knowledge) that would be called the "network guy" in my company :)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know a good solution native to Windows, always had better tools already installed :) In PRTG I think creating a Packet Sniffer per network card should be enough: https://www.paessler.com/manuals/prtg/packet_sniffer_header_sensor.htm