# Monitor Windows Server network data transfer

Tags: windows, networking, monitoring, traffic, transfer

I would like to monitor the amount of data transferred (Network Out) in a Windows Server. The traffic is composed mainly of files downloaded from IIS.

Is there some software or Windows Feature that I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I monitor network usage on a Windows server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/707892/how-do-i-monitor-network-usage-on-a-windows-server)

Comment: LTPCGO yes, the tools mentionted on that post should work, thanks